# How to edit an Item in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem

In my code-behind, how can I edit a value in the ListView ?
I have this :

```
<ListView x:Name="EntreesListView">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Entrees" 
                      Width="Auto" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

And this :

```
// Select all data in my database and add them into my column
private void ListViewAllEntrees()
{
   using (var selectAllEntrees = new Database1Entities())
   {
       var selectName =
           from monEntreeList
           in selectAllEntrees.Entrees
           select monEntreeList;
           foreach (var entree in selectName)
           {
              EntreesListView.Items.Add(new {entree.Name});
           }
// Now I want to edit for example the value at index 5
// I click on a button which is in my ListView too
var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
int indexEntrees = EntreesListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
// Now I have my index
// I can RemoveAt(indexEntrees) and make a new Add but it is not a solution
```

So how can I do to edit the Value Name at index 5 please ?

Comment: NO. SubItems does not exist in WPF. Go up. This is not a duplication.  Please read before post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods to accomplish this task.

Instead of adding each item in list. You can use

```
EntreesListView.ItemSource = selectName;
EntreesListView.Refresh();
```

now your answer, how to get or modify 5th or any element
on some event when you get index of the element which is clicked

```
//get the item from original list
var obj = selectName[index];
//make changes to your object and again change the ItemSource
EntreesListView.ItemSource = selectName;
EntreesListView.Refresh();
```